# Super globals, are they common to all clients?

Tags: php, ajax, superglobals

Are super globals such as $_POST or $_SESSION common to all clients or does the web server have some "under the hood" method for creating new contexts for each request?

For example, I'm working on a site where all users can browse content on the site but must login to make changes. The login is done through AJAX. Lets imagine two users "A" and "B", using different computers, have both successfully logged in and navigate to the same part of the site that has a form where they can now add some information, say a new concert listing. Each form is sent via AJAX to a php file for processing. Because both forms are essentially instances of the same form their keys are the same. User "A" fills out the form and submits it first. The key:value pairs of the form are now in the $_POST variable. Immediately after user "B" submits a form with a different set of values. Did user "B" just overwrite all of the form data in the $_POST super global that user "A" had just written?

Comment: Those arrays are set up per request, two separate (http) requests => two separate php instances => two separate sets of _POST, _SESSION, ....

Comment: Requests are isolated from each other. If they weren't, no one would use such a language. Person A won't overwrite anything that person B is using / submitting. This means PHP is aware of concurrency issues and you don't have to worry about things going all over the place for no good reason.

Comment: Ok, great. Thank you for the response, and this is what I suspected. What I'm getting from this is that is isn't necessary to set cookies in order for the server to know which client it's interacting with. And, consequently, session ID/info can live exclusively on the server and CSRF attacks as well as session fixation attacks are a non-issue, right? Forgive me If I've grossly misunderstood something here, and thank you for your help!

Comment: the server identifies the client for you. but http is stateless - so if you need to know who they are over multiple requests then you would need sessions\cookies

Comment: Unless you let server know who your client is by sending a cookie / some sort of identification, then it can't identify a particular user.